# node js не работает на хостинге

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, dokku

Возникла проблема с запуском node js серверной части на удаленном хостинге.

Вчера оформил машину на cloud.digitalocean com( не является рекламой )
машинку оформил на Ubuntu Dokku 0.9.4 on 16.04

Все настроил, залил проект:

Иерархия:

```
~/public/index.html
~/Procfile
~/app.js
~/package.json
```

#### Содержимое:

*/public/index.html*

```
<h1>main page</h1>
```

*/Procfile*

```
web: node app.js
```

*/package.json*

```
{
  "name": "dokku-demo-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.*",
    "npm": ">=1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.0"
  }
}
```

*/app.js*

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

console.log('create server');
http.createServer(function(request, response){

  console.log(`Запрошенный адрес: ${request.url}`);
  if(request.url.startsWith("/public/")){

    // получаем путь после слеша
    var filePath = request.url.substr(1);
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, data){

        if(error){

            response.statusCode = 404;
            response.end("Ресурс не найден!");
        }   
        else{
            response.end(data);
        }
        return;
    })
}
else{
    console.log('address is wrong');
    // во всех остальных случаях отправляем строку hello world!
    response.end("Hello World!");
}}).listen(50241, console.log('server run...'));
```

Логи:

```
root@server:/# dokku logs interactive_manager
2017-09-21T09:46:40.771912198Z app[web.1]: create server
2017-09-21T09:46:40.773412104Z app[web.1]: server run...
```

В консоль пишет, а страницу не отдает, и вообще на запросы не реагирует. При попытке входа на сайт пишет:

```
Не удается получить доступ к сайту
Превышено время ожидания ответа от сайта *тут мой IP*.
Попробуйте сделать следующее:...
```

Лог консоли:

```
GET http://мой IP:50241/public/index.html 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Comment: `}).listen(50241, console.log('server run...'));` - нет.

Comment: поправил, спс, не перенеслось сюда, в оригинале есть

Comment: Не в скобках дело, а в том, когда console.log вызывается.

Comment: так, а когда он должен вызываться? Сейчас, если я все правильно понимаю, вызывается после начала прослушивания порта, или нет?

Comment: А, забыл сказать, на локалхоте все работает

Comment: Нет, не после начала, а до. `setTimeout(console.log("Done"), 3000)` когда на консоль выводится - сразу или через 3 секунды?

Comment: сразу, не через 3 сек

Comment: Вот и в твоём коде - тоже.

Comment: хорошо, как починить, чтобы создавался сервер?

Comment: `fucntion () { console.log('server run...') }` будет выводиться когда надо. Но это не поможет от проблемы из вопроса, только сможешь узнать, стартует ли сервер.

Comment: сделал так }).listen(50241, function(){setTimeout(console.log("Done"), 13000)}); 
все равно сразу присылает